# MacBook Pro Retina 2015 heating up

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I have MacBook Pro 13' Retina 2015. When I connect the charger the magnet connector heats up, but when charging is complete and the green light comes on everything is normal with no heat.

Also, when I am using the Mac whether on battery or while on charge, the area above the fans heat up too - especially when using Google Chrome. Other times it wont heat up.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues. A laptop stand seemed to help.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of oversimplifying things, when your MBP is charging it needs to receive enough power from the AC outlet in order to charge the battery. However, when charging is complete and if the MBP is still connected to AC power, the charging process effectively goes into a *float* phase where it just keeps your battery charged and does not require the same amount of power coming through. So, it makes perfect sense that while *charging* there will be more heat as compared to while it's *floating* (for want of a better word).

If the heat while charging seems excessive to you (or you're just concerned about it), you can reset the System Management Controller (SMC). To do this:

1. Shut down your MBP
2. Keep the MagSafe adapter (power cable) **plugged in**.
3. Press at the same time <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>control</kbd> (on the **left** side of the built-in keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. Let go
5. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

After doing this, use your computer for a while (incl. Google Chrome) to see if there is a change in the behaviour.

If you still have concerns about when Google Chrome is being used, you can change the hardware acceleration setting within Chrome. To do this:

1. Launch Google Chrome
2. Go to Chrome > Preferences (or just press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> keyboard shortcut
3. At the bottom of the page, click on *Show advanced settings...*
4. Look for the **System** subheading in the new settings that appear
5. Uncheck the *Use hardware acceleration when available* option
6. Restart Google Chrome

Let us know how you go.

Comment: I follow your steps but still the magnet connector and Body heat up

Comment: Is this something new that's just started happening, or has it aways happened? And how long have you had your computer? I'm just trying to get a sense of whether you actually have a problem, or whether it's just normal for your model. I've done a quick check and the average temperature for your model while idle is 44°C (about 111°F) and 99°C (about 210°F) when under heavy load. Does this seem to fit your scenario? As for the MagSafe connector (and even the MBP), you can take it into an Apple Store to check (they won't charge you to look at it).